# Random spaces between textures

Tags: texture, 2d-graphics, tile-based-rendering

I am trying to make Terraria like game using WGPU and rust. There are gaps between tiles. The gaps are bigger and more common as I get far from world center. I've read that nearest filtering should help, hovewer I am already using it.

[image]
[image]

This is my code for calculating tile positions:

```
glam::vec3(                            
    self.world_center.x + chunk_size * 
    (chunk.coords.0 as f32) - 
    chunk_size / 2.0 + self.block_size 
    / 2.0 + self.block_size * (x as 
    f32),
    self.world_center.y + chunk_size * 
    (chunk.coords.1 as f32) - 
    chunk_size / 2.0 + self.block_size 
    / 2.0 + self.block_size * (y as 
    f32),
    0.0,
)
```

x and y is a position of a tile in a  chunk. Tile (0, 0) is on the bottom left.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: can you discribe how you calculate the positions of your tiles? Maybe code would help to understand what happens

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's already there.

Comment: Does this problem occur only vertically? If so, please check if your tile has the same number of pixels in x and y direction. At the moment I would say that the number of pixels in x-direction is smaller than the number of pixels in y-direction.

Comment: It also occurs horizontally. The player is just not far enough from the world center on a Y axis to see it.

Comment: Since you are using floats (`f32`), I would suggest that you round all resulting numbers up (`ceil` function) and see if that makes a difference. Another usual (and better) trick is to add "a half-pixel" size and then use the default rounding function.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It's bug in wgpu, if I use OpenGL backend everything is ok. The problem only occurs when using Vulkan.

Comment: What makes you so sure that it is a bug? Do you have a related bug report that you can share? Such artifacts can be caused by many things, for example, rounding of numbers. 2 APIs (Vulkan and OGL) might come to different valid results because they process things in a different order or they use different algorithms for the same thing. Doesn't mean it's a bug.